# Sort column by header names

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

In Microsoft Excel 2013, how can I change the column order based on the header names?

e.g. if I have:

[image]

I'd like Microsoft takes eight to automatically reorder columns to the order C, B, D, E, F, G. (because in lexicographical order: C: is_aquatic < B: a_bird < D: is_black < E: is_blind < F: is_blue < G: is_brown)

I use  Microsoft Excel 2013 Professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: You would have to put the order in a list somewhere to reference, then create new columns using a MATCH to grab the index to use. With that index you would simply fill out that column.  Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: @EricF Thanks, a bit more tedious than what I would have expected, but makes sense. Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to put the order in a list somewhere to reference, then create new columns using a MATCH to grab the index to use. With that index you would simply fill out that column. Hopefully this makes sense